# PHP: How to increment seq number

Tags: php, arrays, increment

How can i increase the seqnr if the id is the same like example below.

```
ID   SeqNr
111   1
111   1
111   1
222   2
222   2
333   3
555   4
555   4
```

I have an array with repeated id so if the id's are the same i want the seqNr to be 1 and if the id's are different then the seqnr should increment.

```
<?php
$array = [
    ['id' => 111, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 111, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 111, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 222, 'name' => 'two'],
    ['id' => 333, 'name' => 'three'],
    ['id' => 444, 'name' => 'four'],
    ['id' => 444, 'name' => 'four'],
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value['id'];
    $seqNr = 1;

    echo " ID: " . $id . " SeqNr " . $seqNr;
}
?>
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us what a sample output would look like?

Comment: @waterloomatt Output atm: ID: 111 SeqNr 1 ID: 111 SeqNr 1 ID: 111 SeqNr 1 ID: 222 SeqNr 1 ID: 333 SeqNr 1 because seqnr is not incrementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = [
    ['id' => 111, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 111, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 111, 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => 222, 'name' => 'two'],
    ['id' => 333, 'name' => 'three'],
    ['id' => 444, 'name' => 'four'],
    ['id' => 444, 'name' => 'four'],
];
$seqNr = 0;
$lastid= 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value['id'];
    if($lastid!==$value['id']){
        $seqNr++;
    }
    $lastid=$value['id'];
    echo "<pre>";
    echo " ID: " . $id . " SeqNr " . $seqNr;
    echo "</pre>";

}
?>



 ID: 111 SeqNr 2
 ID: 111 SeqNr 2
 ID: 111 SeqNr 2
 ID: 222 SeqNr 3
 ID: 333 SeqNr 4
 ID: 444 SeqNr 5
 ID: 444 SeqNr 5
```

Comment: Ty! This is almost it. How come the number starts from 2?

Comment: Ah nvm! Because the seq number starts with 1.

Comment: because it increments and writes because it is true in the first option $ seqNr = 0; try